# How to have short auto-incremented keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In an App, I want to have short links for very special urls.

When storing the first object, I want its key to be "a", and followed by "b" like that, up to probably ... `abc..n`, and not the firebase keys which are kinda ugly in urls.

Also, I cannot use the google url shortener, this should be on the App's own domain name for branding purposes as per client's requirements.

1. Is there a way to do this economically.
2. Maintain unique keys.
3. Not have more than one user write to the same key and replacing it.

This is all done in Firebase functions backend, please show code examples if possible.

Still on the normal database, no Firestore yet.

**Edit**

Ok, I figure I could use a transection to increment some number, on success, take the number as a new unique key and write to another location.

But I can't seem to figure out the completion part with Javascript, but for Java, this is quite clear. How do I get the version of the following with Javascript.

**This is from** :: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions

```
DatabaseReference upvotesRef = ref.child("links/autoincIndex");
upvotesRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
  @Override
  public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
    Integer currentValue = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
    if (currentValue == null) {
      mutableData.setValue(1);
    } else {
      mutableData.setValue(currentValue + 1);
    }

    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
  }

  @Override
  public void onComplete(DatabaseError e, boolean b, DataSnapshot s) {
    //I could ...
     if(e == null && b){
         String newAutoKey = s.val();
         db.child("links").child(newAutoKey).set(supposedPayload);
     }
  }
});
```

**EDIT ::** Ok, I ended up with this, though not alphabet based, it's at-least getting there.

```
return src.child('autoId').transaction(function (d) {
        return (d || 0) + 1;
}, function (e, committed, snapshot) {
    if (e) {
         console.log('Failed abnormally!', e);
         return;
    }
    return objRef.child(snapshot.val()).set(payload);
});
```

Comment: All sound like requirements for a feasible piece of software. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeah, but quite hacky, please see edit.